# Does im2double() behave like double() for larger dimension arrays in MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix

My code is to  getting images from file and and converting images to vector form.

```
directory = 'C:\Users\Guest\Desktop\FaceRecog\TrainingSet\';
images = dir(strcat(directory,'*.bmp'));
lengthOfFile = length(images);
[m,n] = size(imread(strcat(directory,images(1).name)));
vectorDim = m*n; 
Subjects = zeros(vectorDim,lengthOfFile);

for i=1:lengthOfFile
   imagePath = strcat(directory,images(i).name);
   Temp = reshape(imread(imagePath),[],1);
   Subjects(:,i)=Temp;
end

DblInxSubj = im2double(Subjects);
```

Matlab  Variables area shows "DblInxSubj" Matrix 77760*40 in size and double type logically  correct(and respect to my calculations,too) but when i print a part of this matrix `DblInxSubj(1,:)` MATLAB printed numbers in a range 0-255 not btw in 0-1.

Finally,im2Double() is not working  to convert larger dimensions array ?

```
for i=1:lengthOfFile
  imagePath = strcat(directory,images(i).name);
  Temp = reshape(imread(imagePath),[],1);
   Subjects(:,i)=Temp;
end
```

When i changed the statement `Subjects(:,i)=Temp;` as `Subjects(:,i)=im2Double(Temp);` i get correct matrix's indexes values in a range 0-1.I don't understand where the difference exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between `double()` and `im2double()` is that `double()` converts the number into type `double`, so

```
double(uint8(8))
> 8
```

but `im2double()` converts from typical integer image range (0-255) to typical double image range (0-1). Thus

```
im2double(uint8(8))
> 0.0314
```

But careful!! If the image is already a double, then it returns the same value, as converting a double image to double is doing nothing to it.

```
im2double(8)
> 8
```

Comment: @Moustafa51 I can not run your first code, so I would say it shoudl be working. post a MCVE if you want me to try. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Okay thank you i noticed when i declare zero matrix Subjects that double type and not getting indexes from Temp matrix as uint8 type! thank you